# Class Instantiation Inside Member Function

Tags: c++, oop, recursion, instantiation

Is is safe to instantiate a class inside a member function of that class?  For example, let's say I have class `CMyClass` with member function `CMyClass::MemberFunc`, and I want to create another instance of `CMyClass` inside of `CMyClass::MemberFunc`.

```
void CMyClass::MemberFunc( void )
{
    CMyClass * pMyClass = new CMyClass();
}
```

Is this legal/safe?  I know it compiles.  What I am concerned about is recursion.  Will I run into a recursion error when I instantiate `CMyClass` the first time from the main application?

```
void main( void )
{
    static CMyClass * s_pMyClass = new CMyClass(); // Will this cause recursion?
}
```

Or, will recursion only occur only if the specific member function with the additional class instance is called?

```
void CMyClass::MemberFunc( void )
{
    CMyClass * pMyClass = new CMyClass();
    pMyClass->MemberFunc(); // Pretty sure this will cause a recursive loop.
}
```

In other words, can I safely instantiate a given class within a member function of that class, so long as I do not call that member function of the second instance of that class?  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't more or less safe than instantiating any other object. Note that in your example at the bottom, the recursion is strictly based on the fact that the method calls itself; it would recurse indefinitely regardless.

In sum: you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

A (member)function calling itself is known as recursion.

> Is this legal/safe?

```
void CMyClass::MemberFunc( void )
{

    CMyClass * pMyClass = new CMyClass();

    delete pMyClass ;  // newly added.

}
```

Partially correct. Because every `new` operation should have a `delete` operation accompanied on the specific instance to return the resources back to free store. Other than memory-leak the above snippet is fine.

> Or, will recursion only occur only if the specific member function with the additional class instance is called?

```
void CMyClass::MemberFunc( void )
{
    CMyClass * pMyClass = new CMyClass();
    pMyClass->MemberFunc(); // Pretty sure this will cause a recursive loop.
}
```

Yes, and after some time you should run out of memory as there is no way of destructor being called for the specific instance as `CMyClass::MemberFunc` is being called recursively.( assuming `delete pMyClass;` as the end statement in the member function )

Also, there is no need to place `void` in the argument list when the method don't receive any parameters. I think, it is `C` style.

Answer (score 1):

Correct, unless you explicitly call that member function from the second instance created, you will not cause recursion.  Of course, recursion isnt always a bad thing, so long as you have some kind of base-case condition to break out.

Comment: Or if its something silly like, creating a new instance of the class within a constructor, which would invoke the constructor and cause infinite recursion

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't cause recursion - your compiler would flag it as an error if it did. I suspect you really want to create a static instance of your class (e.g. a singleton). Can you post a real-world use-case illustrating what you want to do?

Comment: Why would the compiler flag recursion as an error?  Its a perfectly valid programming tool.  The only way it could know if it was infinitely recursive, or that it was even recursive in the first place is if it actually analyzed and tried to run the code

Comment: @Dan Classes and structs cannot be declared recursively in C++.

Comment: You can't declare a class or struct within itself, but you can still instantiate one within a member function, as he has described in his examples above

Comment: And a simple real-world use-case would be a copy function, that returns a new instance of the invoked object, not just another pointer or reference to it

Comment: @Dan "You can't declare a class or struct within itself, but you can still instantiate one within a member function, as he has described in his examples above" - did I suggest differently?

Comment: I don't know about recursive class declaration, but I know for a fact that structures can be declared recursively because I've done it.  You have to use the structure's tag, like this: `typedef struct STRUCTURE_TAG { struct STRUCTURE_TAG * prev; struct STRUCTURE_TAG * next; LPVOID item; } STRUCTURE_T, *LPSTRUCTURE_T;`

Comment: @Jim No, you haven't. You have declared  a structure containing pointers to its type.

Comment: @Neil you said that the recursion would cause a compiler error, and the only case it would is in recursive declaration, which wasn't even brought up as a subject in the question

Comment: @Dan "What I am concerned about is recursion" from the question.

Comment: @Neil and recursion referring to the function invoking itself, explicit or implicitly, i assume.  I can't speak for Jim, but that is the way I would interpret his question and concerns from the way he wrote the post, and the example code provided, which in no way indicated recursive declaration of class objects

Comment: @Dan Your interpretation of the question and mine differ, obviously. Let us leave it at that.